# Does network service discovery on android allows automatic connection after first connection (persistent connection)?

Tags: android, service-discovery, network-service, nsd

I want to have an automatic connection between any two devices after the first connection has happened. Does nsd on android provide such functionality? I have refered this link for nsd on android http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html
 Also,we can discover multiple devices on the same network, but can we connect multiple devices on that same network?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use socket for connection. Once the service is resolved, your application receives detailed service information including an IP address and port number. This is everything you need to create your own network connection to the service.